# Sending Cookies with Process.Start

Tags: vb.net, cookies, process.start

Can someone please tell me how you would send a cookie value when you are using process.start with Internet Explorer. I have a routine in VBnet that stores a persistent cookie and I have used InternetGetCookie to confirm it is actually there. But now I want to go to a url with process.start using IE and I need to send that cookie.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

process.start runs a new process, so it can be used to open up internet explorer.

if you wanna send cookies, you may use arguments and pass them into the IE, if IE uses this type of call.

but there is other type of cookie hijacking which needs you to know about XSS attacks.
in this approach the target site which you want to steal cookies from, should have an XSS bug and its cookies should not be httponly, or it should have a bug like apache does which allows you to steal httponly cookies!

But directly answer to stealing cookies with process.start is "it's impossible". :)

Comment: Thanks but I am not trying to steal any cookies. I have my own Cookies to a site I log on with my username/password. I want to be able to start IE with process.start and use the persistent cookies on my machine. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: IE stores cookies in files, if you wanna access them, you may read those files...